# The limit as rate parameter of $\Gamma$ distribution goes to $0$

Tags: probability

Consider a $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution. We will assume the shape-rate version that is has density
$$
\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x}
$$
typically it is assumed $\alpha, \beta >0$. Is it possible to obtain something non-degenerate as  $\beta \to 0$ ? (e.g. by choosing $\alpha(\beta)$ in a clever way).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. In fact, we can prove that
$$
\lim_{\beta\to0}\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}=0
$$
for *any* function $\alpha(\beta)>0$. Using calculus and Stirling's formula, one can show that
$$
\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}<\frac{C}{\log(1/\beta)}
$$
for some absolute constant $C>0$.

Since $\lim_{\beta\to 0^+}\frac{C}{\log(1/\beta)}=0$, it follows by the squeeze theorem that $$
\lim_{\beta\to0}\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}=0.
$$